# Submenu exceeds margin of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, submenu

[Another Solution]:
Using Jquery it's possible to know the distance of the menu to the window, so to each menu it's needed to test if its distance is less than 0 when the mouse is hover it. If it's less than 0 ,use css to reposition.

JQUERY:

```
            var distance = $(window).width() - ($('#your-element').offset().left + $('#your-element').width());
            if(distance<0){
                /* manage if the menu that exceeds the window*/
            }
```

---

I am trying to code a sub-menu with Html and CSS.
Till now it's working fine, but if the menu has too much levels, it exceeds the margin.

Is there a way to fix this, re-positioning the level when it exceed the margin?

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/mag2v/19/

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">PRODUCTS</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">E-COMMERCE</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">INTRANET</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">MARKETING</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">HELP</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">F.A.Q</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">CHAT ONLINE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">ABOUT US</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">OUR TEAM ></a>

                    <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">DEVELOPERS</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">DESIGNERS</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">COMMERCIAL</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">WHERE ARE WE? ></a>

                    <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">BRAZIL ></a>

                            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">SÃO PAULO</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">RIO DE JANEIRO</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">PORTO ALEGRE ></a>

                                    <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">TESTE</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">USA</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">GERMANY</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">CHINA</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">RUSSIA</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">MEDIA</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">JOIN US</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">CONTACT US</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header .container {
    padding:30px 0 50px 0;
}
#header .container .logotipo {
    float:left;
    height:22px;
    width:97px;
}
#header .container .menu {
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:-30px;
}
.menu ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:40px;
    position:relative;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
/* 1 */
 .menu ul li:nth-child(1) a {
    border-top:3px solid #7F9614;
    color:#7F9614;
    display:block;
    padding:29px 0 9px 0;
}
.menu ul li a {
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:Gisha;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:32px 0 9px 0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu ul li:hover a {
    border-top:3px solid #7F9614;
    color:#7F9614;
    display:block;
    padding:29px 0 9px 0;
}
/* 2 */
 .menu ul li > ul {
    border-top:3px solid #7F9614;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:240px;
}
.menu ul li > ul.sub-menu li {
    float:left;
    margin-left:-40px;
    width:100%;
}
.menu ul li > ul.sub-menu li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-bottom:1px dotted #7F9614;
    border-top:none;
    color:#7F9614;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 20px;
    word-break:break-all;
}
.menu ul li > ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
    background:#7F9614;
    color:#fff;
}
/* 3... */
 .menu .sub-sub-menu {
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
}
.menu .sub-sub-menu {
    border-left:1px dotted #7F9614;
    border-top:none;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

Comment: Here's the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/guilhermeturatti/mag2v/1/

Comment: show your code in the question. Thats why SO doesn't allow you to post a fiddle without showing code

Comment: You're going 5 levels deep, the 4 sub menus alone are `960px` wide combined, offset by `437px` on the 'About Us' link. So there's nowhere for it to go, if it stays going right you'll need at least `1396px`, and if it switches to go left it will go `523px` off the screen on the left. So either way you're just making a good example of why you shouldn't keep adding levels on a horizontal drop down menu.

Comment: Midia?  Do you mean "Media" in that drop down item?  Just a heads-up.

Comment: Also, you tagged jQuery on this question, but this is a CSS-only menu.  Are you going to use jQuery?  If so, you can test for the right edge of each menu item and reposition accordingly... maybe change which class is attached to any menu item that would float right out of the window to a class that just positions the item to the left rather than the right...

Comment: Sorry about "midia", I'm brazilian and here we write like this. My mistake. And yes, I intend to use jquery, because I don't think it's possible to fix that just with CSS.

Comment: @FiLeVeR10 even if we display 3rd level on left the problem remains

Comment: @user3127499 of course it does, that's what I'm saying. It can be contained however; I'll post the answer, but I still say this is a bad idea.

Comment: @user3127499 are you able to edit the html as well, or does this all need to be done with just css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***note:*** a menu like this is a bad idea, and the issue you're having is a good example of why that is. Look around, there're good reasons most sites don't do this, and even more reasons not to do this without javascript.

That being said, it *is* possible to make it work with just `HTML` AND `CSS`.

You would want to use media queries to alter the `CSS` based on the window size; like:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {/*just change 800 to whatever you need*/
    /*css here*/
}
```

I made a working example [**in this fiddle...**](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/3EeK2/)

It's not without issues/bugs, but it's just to illustrate the concept. I did add an empty `li` with a class of `trigger` which shows when the menus need to collapse.

I also made just a few changes to your existing `CSS`, and added comments so that you can see what's changed.

This kind of issue is typically solved by the main menu having only one dropdown level, and the pages inside of it that have additional links would display those additional links in a secondary navigation on those pages instead of trying to put `10`lbs of "stuff" in a `5`lb bag.

Like [**this**](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop) where they've made a secondary navigation out of the 3 blocks below the page introductory content (for you, for business, for developers). Most sites handle this issue in a similar fashion.

Comment: good one its not that i havent thought of this but changing the menu structure was not his question why it was going outside margin of page is.i have mentioned that it depends on the grid size and the size of the menu should be relative to grid size and the size should remain in grid size and another suggestion its better change the drop down levels background colour so its more identifiable

Comment: It's going outside of the area because it doesn't fit, it has to adapt in order to work. My answer is to use media queries, menu structure remains the same, only its appearance changes as needed. He can do whatever he wants with background colors, media queries can contain it in the grid. My example is just to illustrate how to use the media queries, what he does with it from there is up to him.

Comment: hey lets wrap this up i agree with  what you just said and i am wondering isnt it that i was telling from the beginning citing the total width and height  of each indiviual li tags ,I left it to the reader to put two and two together and in my defense i tried to show his menu without change to structure and did not change the code much.To show that even if the menu which goes out of range of page is shown on left side still causes problem since the total width of tag exceeds that of the menu and page

Answer (score 0):

[Solved Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mag2v/21/)

```
.menu .sub-sub-menu1{position:absolute;left:-100%;top:0;}// does the trick alter
```

1. -100% to display the menu out side page margin on left of drop down menu level2
2. Alter Html content `.sub-sub-menu` to `.sub-sub-menu1`or name you like use seperate sub menu for sub levels so that they are displayed on left of level2 ie level3 on left of level2 and level4 on left of level3 son even with this next level can be very difficult to accommodate with current code

[**Suggestion In case you have to you such deep /multi level drop downs (Demo)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kpth7/)

I think it would be better if you use mix of both after sub sub menu the next drop down should be displayed as vertical menu that helps to limit the menu within the range of the grid

your padding and margin and all make your menu fatter (consume space **240px X 37px**) you should try to limit sum of length all visible drop down menu  under **1288.472px** which is size of the  menu rendered in my browser.
basically what i am trying say is **that give padding and margin to the drop down menu (li and a tags )**  in such a way that when most deep dropdown is visible **the total length should be less than that of grid size you are using**

Comment: This only fixes one of the many issues that are present, and is not a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep below steps in mind.

1. It is always advisable to reset your html tags to reduce browser inconsistencies about margin, padding etc.

two most famous reset css are :

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ - I prefer this.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

1. UL by default has list style hence overwrite it. **list-style:none;**

JS fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/mag2v/22/ and Now here is the modified css:

```
#header .container {
padding:30px 0 50px 0;
}
#header .container .logotipo {
float:left;
height:22px;
width:97px;
}
#header .container .menu {
float:left;
 margin-left:20px;
margin-top:-30px;
}
.menu ul li {
float:left;
list-style:none;
margin-left:40px;
position:relative;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
list-style: none;
padding:0;
}
/* 1 */
.menu ul li:nth-child(1) a {
border-top:3px solid #7F9614;
color:#7F9614;
display:block;
padding:29px 0 9px 0;
}
.menu ul li a {
color:#000;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
font-family:Gisha;
font-size:16px;
padding:32px 0 9px 0;
text-decoration:none;
}
.menu ul li:hover a {
border-top:3px solid #7F9614;
color:#7F9614;
display:block;
padding:29px 0 9px 0;
}
/* 2 */
.menu ul li > ul {
border-top:3px solid #7F9614;
display:none;
position:absolute;
width:240px;
}
.menu ul li > ul.sub-menu li {
float:left;
margin-left:0;
width:100%;
}
.menu ul li > ul.sub-menu li a {
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
border-bottom:1px dotted #7F9614;
border-top:none;
color:#7F9614;
font-size:14px;
padding:10px 0px 10px 20px;
word-break:break-all;
}
.menu ul li > ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
background:#7F9614;
color:#fff;
}
/* 3... */
.menu .sub-sub-menu {
position:absolute;
left:100%;
top:0;
}
.menu .sub-sub-menu {
border-left:1px dotted #7F9614;
border-top:none;
word-break:break-all;
}
```